# Using defer or load_only with sqlmodel will return primary ID. How can avoid this natively?

Tags: python, sql, fastapi, sqlmodel

I'm using SQLModel to declare this model:

```
class UserBase(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: Optional[int]= Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    name: str
    JWT: str
    password: str
```

When I try to get it with this statement:

```py
statement = select(UserBase).where(
    UserBase.name == user.name,
    UserBase.password == user.password).options(
        load_only(UserBase.JWT))
```

So I want to load only JWT from model **or** load everything but `UserBase.id` by using defer:

```py
statement = select(UserBase).where(
    UserBase.name == user.name, 
    UserBase.password == user.password).options(
        defer(UserBase.id))
```

But SQLmodel will continuosly return UserBase.id. I can fix this by making SQL statement manually, but I want to know is there more native way?

I print all variants with defer or load_only to console - they all have `SELECT userbase.id, userbase."JWT"...`

Comment: You can't, really: "the ORM will typically always fetch the primary key columns as these are required to establish the identity for the row." (from the SQLAlchemy documentation). Also be aware that any fields being accessed afterwards (for example in your return model) will trigger another SQL select to fetch those lazily unless `raiseload` is set. If you _really_ want to perform a single fetch without the primary key column, drop the ORM and access the database more directly, but the primary key by itself should not incur any real performance penalty

Comment: @MatsLindh 
Thanks, there is no performance problem  i just want to hide id information from user because it's not necessary for him to know his auto increment id in my db

Comment: You do that with a ResponseModel  that only include the fields you want to include, instead of having all of them - so on the endpoint you add a response model that only includes the `jwt` field instead of having all of them. You can see an example in the reference documentation for a user model that has a password field: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/#add-an-output-model